# Unable to run spark.eventLog.enabled true and spark.eventLog.dir on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

When I attempt to run the the either line of code on my Databricks notebook I get the following error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax at the keyword true

`spark.eventLog.enabled true`

and SyntaxError: invalid syntax at the keyword dbfs with the following command

`spark.eventLog.dir dbfs:/databricks/unravel/eventLogs/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot configure the spark.eventLog using Databricks notebooks. I would suggest you to follow the below steps.

**Steps to configure the Spark Event Logs:**

**Step1:** Go to **Clusters** => Select a clusters

**Step2:** Click on **Edit** button

**Step3:** Under **Advanced Options** click **Spark** then Spark Config and enter the following:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir dbfs:/databricks/unravel/eventLogs/
```

**Step4:** **Confirm and restart**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [Deploying Unravel for Azure Databricks from Azure Marketplace](https://docs.unraveldata.com/en/az-databricks-marketplace.html)